# How to determine the logical type of a linux network device

Tags: linux, networking, iproute

with logical I mean everything legal in the command  `ip link` as in, for instance:

```
ip link add link dum0 name dum0.200 type vlan protocol 802.1Q id 200
```

where the logical type would be "vlan". All valid types are, to quote the man page:

```
vlan | veth | vcan | dummy | ifb | macvlan | macvtap | can | bridge | ipoib | ip6tnl | ipip | sit | vxlan |gre | gretap | ip6gre | ip6gretap | vti
```

Note that this clearly is not the physical device type (like ethernet, wifi, ppp etc.) as asked in this question: [Detect network connection type in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475420/detect-network-connection-type-in-linux), which does contain a gem of a reference to the physical type [if_arp.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/linux/if_arp.h) which led me to test for it:

```
find /sys/class/net ! -type d | xargs --max-args=1 realpath | while read d ; do b=$(basename $d) ; n=$(find $d -name type) ; echo -n $b' ' ; cat $n ; done
dum0.200 1
dum0.201 1
dum1.300 1
dum1.301 1
dummy0 1
ens36 1
ens33 1
lo 772
dum0 1
dum1 1
wlan0 1
```

But which apparently finds both dummy, vlan and wlan devices to be of type `ARPHRD_ETHER`.

Does somebody know more?